# AngularJS Rails giving blank page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm following the tutorials at [thinkster.io/angular-rails](https://thinkster.io/angular-rails)

So far I got to end of this stage

> Integrating the Front-end with the Asset Pipeline

But now my app is giving me a blank page with no errors on Chrome console or WebRick console either

This is what I see when trying to go to http://localhost:3000/#/home

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 18:57:54 -0300
Processing by ApplicationController#angular as HTML
  Rendered layouts/application.html.erb within layouts/application (95.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 177ms (Views: 176.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 18:57:59 -0300
```

If I try to go to http://localhost:3000, I see all this on WebRick

```
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300
Processing by ApplicationController#angular as HTML
  Rendered layouts/application.html.erb within layouts/application (55.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 106ms (Views: 105.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-b0009f9e25467a0cf98029ba5cea5cc6.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/application-ebcbb47a1897dc658f254d3ed27f8059.css?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/angular/angular-2d5a33d94b093db45bb7a9ede7fb19cd.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/app-aa9fab9c243b33abeab86ad1957ed641.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router-baa37ca0378f13b403a5dbcdc9aa5155.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/angular-rails-templates-4c1f2ca110b30578d07f9cc497121e81.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/home/mainCtrl-b29014101de152dbd6e2c9dc5c28ece7.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/posts/posts-35d84f25af005d974cc5973c2ef26354.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/posts/_posts-bc8b8c3f542abacc3b5e9ad028f3cb96.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/posts/postsCtrl-5ef10d79585a7fc3d40aa58e799fbf70.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/application-c0bc5d796fa367b0c956d35d8a01fdb4.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/home/_home-583f0c3e136561b0bb8b62359042f948.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300


Started GET "/assets/application-c0bc5d796fa367b0c956d35d8a01fdb4.js?body=1" for ::1 at 2015-10-14 19:02:09 -0300
```

You can see my source code here 
https://bitbucket.org/federicogiust/flapper-news/src

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

I still had the script tags in the partials _home.html and _posts.html.

I removed the script tags and it works fine now.